# Whitebox GAT Import GeoTIFF tool error

Tags: geotiff-tiff, whitebox-gat

I'm trying to run Whitebox GAT's Import GeoTIFF tool.  The following message pops up each time:

[image]

ArcMap's source info says the Tiff I'm trying to import is not compressed or 48/64-bit RGB.  It is a large 32-bit floating point file (~20GB), georeferenced (ie has TFW file) and projected into a StatePlane Coordinate System.  Perhaps the size or projection is causing issues?  I looked at the WhiteboxLog0_0.xml file.  Honestly, it's hard for me to decipher that file in a browser, but the first line is:

"2018-08-30T13:35:07 1535650507206 65 whiteboxgis SEVERE whiteboxgis.WhiteboxGui logException 18 Whitebox 3.4.0. Error Error in MapRenderer"

Comment: Could you check memory availability for Whitebox-GAT by `View | Options and Settings` (and if Java is 64-bit or 32-bit)?

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito.  Says it's running on 64-bit Java.  I have 16 GB of RAM, 64 bit OS, Windows 7 Pro, 2.7 Ghz CPU.

Comment: Max heap: 12.5 GB and Available memory: 11.9 GB.  BTW, what is Max Heap?

Comment: Honestly I do not know about Java Heap. But it seems your computer has plenty of memory available. Provided it is not machine issue, will you try to convert your **tif** to other formats? If you have access to ArcGIS, **flt** format is more easily read. If not, using SAGA **sgrd** format is also WhiteBox-friendly.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I'm trying to split up the tif to see if that helps.  Not a bad idea to convert to different raster format.  Just need to ensure converted DEM is close to original DEM as possible.

Comment: Thanks jbrengel. Dr Lindsay has been improving GeoTiff reader, such as latest WhiteBox-Tools 0.12 (now supports compression) but I am not sure if it also becomes available for WhiteBox-GAT soon... using another format is just a workaround for now...

Comment: @jbrengel I suspect that at 20Gb, it is likely that your GeoTIFF is a 'BigTiff' format, which unfortunately I do not currently support. Kazuhito is correct that I have been making large strides in improving GeoTIFF support in the Whitebox stack, but it has been focused on WhiteboxTools, rather than Whitebox GAT. So you may try to perform the data conversion using WhiteboxTools instead. Ultimately, if you still run into problems, please report the issue on the GitHub issue tracker and any data that you can provide helps me to track bugs.

Comment: It was my impression that the BigTiff format (http://www.bigtiff.org/) was not all that common in the wild but this may be changing. What software did you use to create this 20Gb TIFF file? I think that the standard TIFF format is confined at 4Gb, so this must be a BigTiff reading/writing issue.

Comment: Thank you @WhiteboxDev!  The tiff- created about 10 yrs ago- was downloaded from PASDA (Pennsylvania's GIS Database).  Metadata says final terrain surface generated was ASCII converted to ArcGIS Raster Grid converted to GeoTiff.

Comment: Also, I did split the raster. Tried loading a tile < 4 GB into WBox GAT and got the same error.  Converted a tile to flt format in ArcMap and it imported ok into WBox GAT.  Will report issue on GitHub

Comment: Hi @jbrengel again, try the WhiteboxTools ConvertRasterFormat instead of Whitebox GAT's raster import tools. It will support many more flavours of GeoTIFF than the Whitebox GAT equivalent since that is where current development efforts are focused at present. One of the issues with the GeoTIFF format is that it is so incredibly flexible that it becomes a difficult target for developing a raster reader/writer.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much.  I've been meaning to expand my Python skillset to include WhiteboxTools and your comments are pushing me towards that goal (ever slowly, admittedly :)).

Comment: Sorry, Dr Lindsay @WhiteboxDev  I had no idea how developments of WhiteBox- Tools and WhiteBox-GAT would be going. Will try to lean Python and WhiteBox-Tools.  And thanks again to jbrengel for this topic!